# where is aspnetdb.mdf in mvc3 default sample program?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string

In the default sample appication in mvc3, Where do the details we fill in registration form gets stored?

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I did not find any aspnetdb.mdf file in app_data folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click the 'show all files' option as it is hidden IIRC.

[image]

Comment: thankyou @Sean. But I use visual basic 2010, help me with the same

Comment: Visual Basic 2010, regardless of whether it is VS2010 or Express version has Show All Files in Solution Explorer.